# Group by Date using left join function is showing duplicate dates in result

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to fetch 3 fields grouping by date using left join. The group by date is showing duplicate dates.

Tried in MySQL and it is working fine but it is not working in BigQuery.

```
SELECT DATE(a.transactionDate) as date, 
CASE WHEN b.memberProfileNumber LIKE 'M0%' THEN SUM(a.fromAmount) END AS 
col1,
CASE WHEN b.memberProfileNumber NOT LIKE 'M0%' THEN SUM(a.fromAmount) END 
AS col2
FROM `fashionpoints*` as a
LEFT JOIN `fashionprofile*` as b
ON a.toAccountId = b.id 
WHERE a.fromATC = 'usd' AND
a.type = 'awarding' AND
a.status = 'active'
GROUP BY date
```

Expected output is DISTINCT Date and actual results is duplicating the date.

Expected Output:

[image]

Actual Result:
[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcEvJ.png)

Comment: It would be great if you can share the output you are getting right now.

Comment: Where in that output do you see duplicate dates?

Comment: @SagarR I have added the output that I got. You can see it duplicated the date.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa In bigQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your aggregation wrong. Try to replace with `SUM(CASE WHEN... THEN...ELSE 0 END) as col1/2`

Comment: Thank you! It is working in BigQuery if I put SUM before the CASE but in MySQL, it  need to put after THEN. Anyway thanks again for pointing that out.